# Auto populate dropdown option from sql database depends on another selected dropdown option in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dropdown, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have two selectpicker, Game Name and Game ID.

I want the Game ID to be populate from database based on the Game Name selected.

[image]

My database table :

```
GAME NAME | GAME ID
-------------------
MARIO     | A123
MARIO     | B123
FUNRUN    | F222
CARRACE   | C888
CARRACE   | C999
```

My expected outcome will be :
The dropdown option in **Game ID** depends on the Game Name selected in **Game** dropdown.

How can I achieve this in php? Please help on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've already tagged the correct technologies (javascript/ajax). Add an "on change" event on the first select. When it's changed, pass that value to some PHP endpoint using Ajax and query the database. Then return the results as json and populate the other select box with the response you get from the Ajax request.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a lot of sense from a data or UX point of view. If each ID is specific to each game then why would you put the selected game's ID into another picker which can then be changed? What are you trying to achieve with this user interface? Also I'd expect the ID to already be present in the "value" attribute of each option in the first drop-down, to ensure it uniquely identifies the game (there are no doubt some games in history with the same name). So if you wanted to display the selected ID it would just be some simple JavaScript to get the currently selected ID